# Does the sequence converge (in particular, does it depend on x in this way)?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

I am trying to determine if the following series converges or diverges for values other than $x=-1$

$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{1+x^n}$. I am a little thrown by the (seeming) implication of the question that there should be a single answer, as I seem to obtain divergence for $-1<x<=1$ and convergence for $x<-1$ and $x>1$ as follows:

Define $a_n$ as $\frac{1}{1+x^n}$.

For $-1<x<1$, the $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ of $1+ x^n$ approaches 1. For $-1<x<1$, the $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ of $1+ x^n$ approaches 2, so the limit of the sequence $a_n$ approaches $\frac{1}{2}$ or $1$ respectively. Therefore, the series diverges.

Define $s_n$ as $\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{1+x^n}$ with $x>1$ and $t_n$ as $\sum_{n=1}^{k} \frac{1}{1+x^n}$ with $x<1$.

Then:

For $s_n$ ($x>1$), the $\lim \limits_{n \to \infty}$ of $1+ x^n$ grows without bound in the positive direction (for $x>0$). We can find $N$ such that $1+ x^n > n$ for any $x$, as $x>\sqrt[N]{N-1}$. At that value of N, $1+ x^n = n^p$ for some $p>1$

For $x<-1$, $1+ x^n$ oscillates between increasingly large values of $x^n$ (as $n>1$).

As a result $s_n$ converges by the comparison test and p test (we can find a value of $p>1$ such that $1+x^n = n^p$). But, any partial sum of $t_n < s_n$.

The terms of $s_n$ are positive, and monotonically decreasing to zero. The terms of $t_n$ are equal in absolute value to the terms of $s_n$, but there is some cancellation. Thus, by comparison, $t_n$ converges faster than $s_n$, and in particular, $t_n$ converges

Is that the way to go about a problem like this? It feels a little inelegant, but I think it answers the questions with the tools given. Any suggestions are welcome